# Why is ESLint complaining about "Unnecessary conditional" when checking if an array value exists?

Tags: typescript, eslint

```js
const array = [1,2,3]

if (array[5] === undefined)
  array[5] = 5
```

I'm using Typescript and ESLint and I don't understand why this ESLint error is showing for `array[5] === undefined`:

> Unnecessary conditional, the types have no overlap.ESLint(@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition)

Since this is an array of numbers ESLint is telling me that the check is an unnecessary conditional. But I want to know if the given index holds a value. What am I supposed to do here instead so the error does not show up?

Here is a Sandbox with the error showing: [Sandbox](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.6.4&sourceType=script&code=MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAnjAvDA2gRgDQBMeAzALoBQ5AlgGYwAUiyKWArKRupgK5gAmAUxpUwAvgEpyMeElRsOmVkA&rules=N4IgAgLgngDgpgZwMYCcCWMIFpEBs0B2EA9AQPZYCuBBcSiCAhilFkmQQCZoRocgAuEHBQoyKEAF8gA&tsConfig=N4IgzgLgTglgxhAcgVwDaoMIAsCmcDWYIAXNMjgL5A)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @Quentin It wasn't that hard to edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `array[5]` has the type of `number`, rather than `number | undefined`.

In the following example, the error [is not present](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.6.4&sourceType=script&code=MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAnjAvDA2gRgDQBMeAzALoBQoksAllAKYC2G8SqWArKfBDGAK6MARvQQwAPjH5gAJvQBmNMPRnlyNeTAAUdJhnSZpcxcpkBKcjFbIUnbpg7kgA&rules=N4XyA&tsConfig=N4XyA):

```
const array = [1,2,3]
const item = array[5] as number | undefined

if (item === undefined)
  array[5] = 5
```

Consider setting `"strictNullChecks": true` to be able to operate with `null`s and `undefined`s, and setting `"noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true` to include `… | undefined` in index signature property access:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true
  }
}
```